# How to authenticate user without agetty login prompt?

Tags: linux, shell-script, login, console, authentication

I want to write a shell script based on [cdm](https://github.com/evertiro/cdm) which not only lets the user choose which session to run, but also asks for their *username* and *password*.
Just to give some details: it uses [dialog](https://invisible-island.net/dialog/), which provides curses widgets that can be used in shell scripts. *cdm* is only launched after the user logs in via the console login screen. I want to launch it **before**, so that I can first ask for the user info (via a *dialog* box that I will write), and **then** let them choose the session they want to start.

After that, I use their typed input to log them in and start the chosen session.

I already tried redirection to the *login* program in the following ways:

```
echo "$user $password" | login

#and

login <<< "$user $password"
```

But *login* doesn't seem to accept input redirection, so neither way worked (I didn't see anything about it in the *manpages*, but tried anyway).

Is there a way for doing that via shell script? I found [this perl script](https://askubuntu.com/questions/657229/how-to-validate-passwords-with-pam) that is capable of telling if the input provided is valid, but it does not log them in.
If you can tell me a way of doing this in a language other than bash, it's ok, as long as I can call it from a bash script,  like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

read user
read -s password

#log user in
auth-program "$user" "$password" # if success, now $user is logged in
                                 # and I can start the session
```

I hope you can help me with this.
Thank you in advance!